# How to write regular expression from the Request tab> Cookie Data section to pull CSRF-TOKEN value

Tags: jmeter

[image: Regular Expression]I am trying to write regular expression using Jmeter from the Request tab of the result tree from :Cookie Data:" section and script doesn't pull the value:

[View Results> Request> Cookie Data:[[image: ][1][1]]

Here is the regular expression I have tried:

Name of created variable: csrfToken
Regular Expression: CSRF-TOKEN=(.+?)
Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
Default Value: Not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Regular Expression below

> CSRF-TOKEN=(\w+)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write regular expressions, you can extract any [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) value from JMeter's [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

1. Add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous):

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan
4. That's it, you should be able to refer your CSRF-TOKEN cookie value as `${COOKIE_CSRF-TOKEN}` where required. The same applies to the `${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}`

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression to get whole value of CSRF-TOKEN

```
CSRF-TOKEN=(.*)
```